# listening to webView.loadurl

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am trying to load a page and then executing a javascript code as the following :

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //first javascript code 
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.done" +
                        "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].pause()+'</html>');");
                Log.i("f", "finish");



        }
    });

        webview.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/....");
```

and I have a button when on click on it , it will excute the following code :

```
public void star (View v) {
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].getAttribute(\"src\")+'</html>');");
}
```

but the problem is the src attribute will not be available until execuiting the first javascript code what I need to do is  to listen to the execution of the first javascript code and once it finishes set the button enabled

I have tried to set the button disabled inside the onCreate method and then do the following

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
      //some code
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void done(String html ){
       b.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

but it does not work properly so what should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work properly"? Enable button, after first needed loadUrl called in OnPageFinished.

Comment: I mean that when I press on the button the link should be avaliable after executing the first javascript code but when I click I found it null and I have to wait for few seconds to get the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split done() call and other operations – put it at the end. I suggest to create extra function for this, like this:

> in Java:

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //first javascript code 
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:firstJsWork()");
    }
```

> in JS:

```
function firstJsWork(){
    // your code to process in html
    .......
    // call done in Java
    AndroidInterface.done();
}
```

Thats guaranteed you, that done will be called after all works completed. Check it.